# How to map IP Address to Localhost to access pods from outside the host machine using the IP address?

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

I am using docker desktop and Kubernetes from Docker Desktop
I have created a deployment and a service as given in the below code snippet:
Deployment.yaml:

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: rhap
  name: deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rhap
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rhap
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: image:release1
        name: rhap
```

Service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rhap-service

spec:
  selector:
    app: rhap

  ports:
    - name: cport
      port: 8444
      nodePort: 30080
    - name: iport
      port: 3041
      nodePort: 30081
    - name: bport
      port: 4031
      nodePort: 30082
    - name: uport
      port: 31002
      nodePort: 31002

  type: NodePort
```

I am able to access the port 30080 from the host machine system(Ubuntu VM) as https://localhost:30080 and it opens my application.
But when I try https://ipaddr:30080, from my local laptop, it is not opening the application.
I am able to ping the machine.

I am not able to access https://ipaddr:30080 within my Ubuntu VM as well.

How can I map IPAddress to localhost for accessing my pods from outside the VM?

Comment: `localhost` is the specific IP address 127.0.0.1, and it refers to whatever the current network context is (the system running the browser, the current Kubernetes pod, _etc._).  I don't think the URL `https://:30080` is meaningful without a host name there.  For a NodePort-type Service, you need to use one of the Nodes' DNS names in the URL.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have tried with localhost and IP address of the box.. something like below:
https://localhost:30080

https://<ip-addr>:30080

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because the service doesn't have the same target port as the application's port.

If you do not specify a target port for the service, the service port is assigned to the target port by default.

Comment: This didnt work... I tried the following change in my service.yaml

name: cport
      port: 8444
      targetPort: 8444
      nodePort: 30080
    - name: iport
      port: 3041
      targetPort: 3041
      nodePort: 30081
    - name: bport
      port: 4031
      targetPort: 4031
      nodePort: 30082
    - name: uport
      port: 31002
      targetPort: 31002
      nodePort: 31002